# Is it possible to use arithmetic formulae to use as cell references in Excel (without VBA)?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Assume cell `A1` contains value `10` and `A2` contains value `20`. Then, I need to way to refer to the cell on column `A` and line `10 + 20`. Something that could be imagined as `A{A1+A2}`. Is there a way to preceed so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the INDEX Function:

```
=INDEX(A:A,A1+A2)
```

Comment: @HaiNguyenVan the use of `;` vs `,` is not a typo.  In my local settings, which is EN-US we use `,` not `;`.  and as this site is generally also EN-US the use of `,` for answers is what is used.